# MongoDB - Update an array of documents with two levels deep which matches conditionals from different levels

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, filtering, mongodb-update

What I need to do is only update the **availableWeights** field if the event `id` and `weight` match what I pass in (*ObjectId("67823649279") & 0*) and the `userId` field is "empty" exactly. I will replace the empty fields with `{ userId: ObjectId(), name: "wendy" }`.

For example:

I want to be able to:

1. make sure the `_id` = 636c2c6dcb82e7ae6aac0960
2. Make sure `weights.weight` = 0
3. Make sure `weights.spotsAvailable.userId` = "empty"

Here is an example document:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "636c2c6dcb82e7ae6aac0960"
  },
  "name": "onmygowd",
  "createdBy": {
    "$oid": "636c1778f1d09191074f9690"
  },
  "description": "It's gonnam be a good one",
  "date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1667913330000"
    }
  },
  "location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      0,
      0
    ]
  },
  "weights": [
    {
      "spotsAvailable": [
        {
          "name": "empty",
          "userId": "empty"
        },
        {
          "name": "John",
          "userId": {
            "$oid": "636c1778f1d09191074f9690"
          }
        }
      ],
      "weight": 0
    },
    {
      "spotsAvailable": [
        {
          "name": "empty",
          "userId": "empty"
        },
        {
          "name": "John",
          "userId": {
            "$oid": "636c1778f1d09191074f9690"
          }
        }
      ],
      "weight": 123
    }
  ],
  "eventApplicants": [
    {
      "userId": {
        "$oid": "636c1778f1d09191074f9690"
      },
      "name": "wallace",
      "weight": 123.1
    }
  ]
}
```

I am pretty sure I need to use array filters, but all 3 of my attempts failed:

**1**

```
db.events.updateOne({ _id: ObjectId('636c2c6dcb82e7ae6aac0960'), "weights.weight": 0 },
            { $set: { "weights.spotsAvailable.$[el2]":  { "name": "George", "userId": ObjectId('636c1778f1d09191074f9690') } } },
            { arrayFilters: [ {"el2.userId": "empty"}] })
```

---

**2**

```
db.events.updateOne(db.events.findOne({_id: ObjectId('636c2c6dcb82e7ae6aac0960'), "weights.weight": 0, "weights.spotsAvailable.userId": "empty"},
{$set: {"weights.$[el].spotsAvailable": {"name": "George", "userId": ObjectId('636c1778f1d09191074f9690')}}},
{arrayFilters:[{"el.spotsAvailable.userId": "empty"}] })
```

---

**3**

```
db.events.updateOne({ _id: ObjectId('636c2c6dcb82e7ae6aac0960'), "weights.weight": 0 },
            { $set: { "weights.$[el].spotsAvailable.$[el2]":  { "name": "George", "userId": ObjectId('636c1778f1d09191074f9690') } } },
            { arrayFilters: [ {"el.el2.userId": "empty"}] })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You need the `$` positional operator for

```
weights.$.spotsAvailable.$[el2]
```

Complete query:

```
db.events.updateOne({
  _id: ObjectId("636c2c6dcb82e7ae6aac0960"),
  "weights.weight": 0
},
{
  $set: {
    "weights.$.spotsAvailable.$[el2]": {
      "name": "George",
      "userId": ObjectId("636c1778f1d09191074f9690")
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "el2.userId": "empty"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U66_D1UgIwb)

---

**Solution 2**

Approach 3 is almost right to the answer. You have to add another object for `el` in `arrayFilters`.

```
db.events.updateOne({
  _id: ObjectId("636c2c6dcb82e7ae6aac0960"),
  "weights.weight": 0
},
{
  $set: {
    "weights.$[el].spotsAvailable.$[el2]": {
      "name": "George",
      "userId": ObjectId("636c1778f1d09191074f9690")
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "el.weight": 0
    },
    {
      "el2.userId": "empty"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1wkHQXhZnQE)

Comment: thank you so much can you explain the difference between using .$  and using .$[]

I thought the only reason you used the empty array was so you can use a variable

Comment: `$` is used to update the first matched element with `weight: 0` in the `weights` array. While `$[]` all positional operator will update all the documents in the `weights` array. FYI, I have edit the answer for the Solution 1.

Comment: so could we do an identical query where we don't use el2? Since we will only need to match the first element or... Is it that because we are using an array filter we are technically always filtering all elements so we will always want to use the all operator when we are using array filters? THANKS A BUNCH FOR THE HELP BY THE WAY SAVED ME SO MUCH TIME I WAS REALLY STUCK

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think that is possible. The MongoDB query will complain if you use multiple `$` operators. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LkpauJLYD_W). From my perspective, `arrayFilters` is still needed.

Comment: Hello Yong Shun, I seem to have failed at a similar issue again. If you don't mind taking a quick look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74548212/i-am-trying-to-perform-a-pull-on-a-nested-document-for-all-users-in-the-collect